# What is the product of continuous function spaces over euclidean space?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was wondering what the product of continuous function spaces over eucliden space was. More specifically, if we have $A = C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $B = C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^m)$, then is
$A\times B = C^{\infty}_c (\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m)$?

Thanks

Comment: An element  of $A \times B$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^2$, an element of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m)$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Actually, an element of $A\times B$ is a tuple $(f,g)$ for $f \in A$, $g \in B$. One can certainly identify this tuple with the map $(x,y) \mapsto (f(x), g(y))$, but strictly speaking its not the same.

Comment: @PhoemueX: You are correct; I was just pointing out that the two spaces can't be identified in any way just from co domain considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @copper.hat,

> An element of $A\times B$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^2$, an element of $A\times B = C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m)$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$.

It is just a simple notational problem.